# Recommend tool for automating UI tests for windows forms app

Tags: .net, testing

My team loves using Selenium for automated testing of our web apps.  Can anyone recommend a similar type of tool for testing windows forms apps (meaning desktop apps in .net)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey.
Start with [White](http://white.codeplex.com/). And if won't work for you, search SO, there are questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you've got VS 2010 Premium or Ultimate, [MS Coded UI tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx) support winforms applications

Comment: Unfortunately, I have VS standard.  I guess I'm looking for a 3rd party solution.